# Sequelize hasOne will not allow multiple rows to share the same relationship

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sails.js, sequelize.js

I'm experiencing an issue with sails.js using the Postgres driver:

```
"dependencies": {
    "sequelize": "^1.7.0",
    "pg": "^3.0.3"
}
```

I have an Activity model that has a hasOne relationship to 2 models and belongs to another:

```
classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
        Activity.hasOne(models.Model2);
        Activity.hasOne(models.Model3);
        Activity.belongsTo(models.User);
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is I seem unable to create 2 Activity Instances that share the same Model2 or Model3 row/instance. I declare the first one:

```
Activity.create({}).complete(function(err, activity) {
    if(err) throw err;
    activity.setUser(User_Instance_X)
    activity.setModel2(Model2_Instance_X);
    activity.setModel3(Model3_Instance_X);
    activity.save().complete(db_save_cb);
}
```

If I then declare another one, using the same Model2 & Model3 instance but a different user, then the first row/instance no longer contains a reference to Model2 & 3, and only the latest row/instance contains that reference.

This is puzzling functionality? Is it a lack of understanding on my part or a bug?

Comment: hasOne in Sequelize implies the foreignKey is on the target. Are you sure you are intending for Activity to have a foreignKey on model2/3 or are you expecting Activity to have all the foreign keys?

Comment: Ah, I was expecting Activity to hold the foreign keys.. (thanks)

Comment: Yeah it's a problem we see often. Currently belongsTo adds on source and hasOne adds on target - but hasOne is hardly ever used that way, it's mostly as the reverse of a belongsto - So we're probably changing it so that hasOne works roughly the same as belongsTo (since sometimes belongsTo doesnt semantically make sense, i.e. game does not belong to map but that's the foreign key structure you want)

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot  I'll review my usage of it.. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide the answer we figured out in comments. What OP actually wanted was `belongsTo` for all his associations.

`belongsTo` in Sequelize adds the foreign key on the **source** while `hasOne`adds the foreign key on the **target**.

`hasOne` is actually rarely ever used and is probably due for an api change.

Comment: Thanks so much Mick, that has explained a lot!